# Inserting AND/OR Updating records based off of values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, window-functions

Basically, what I am trying to do is to create a new duplicate row in sourcetable, if CANID exists as a duplicate in targettable. For instance, in this set, CANID '2' exists as a duplicate in targettable, but in source table, it exists only once. What I am trying to accomplish is to have this script create another row with the next available CANID and copy over value for other columns.

[image]

Once ran, the result will look something like this. Notice how the CANID was changed in targettable (For ACTID 6969) to reflect the correct CANID

[image]

Sourcetable:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourcetable]
(
    [CANID] [int] NULL,
    [COLID] [int] NULL,
    [Value1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Value2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Value3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Value4] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Value5] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample data for Sourcetable

```
INSERT INTO sourcetable (CANID,COLID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5) VALUES (1,21,'0.25','6.25','Chicago','-0.25','16');
INSERT INTO sourcetable (CANID,COLID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5) VALUES (2,65,'0.65','6.19','Dallas','0.15','65');
INSERT INTO sourcetable (CANID,COLID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5) VALUES (3,91,'1.65','3.25','Denver','NULL','65');
INSERT INTO sourcetable (CANID,COLID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5) VALUES (4,55,'1','42','Miami','0.25','NULL');
```

Target table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].targettable 
(
    [CANID] [int] NULL,
    [ACCTID] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample data for targettable:

```
INSERT INTO targettable (CANID,ACCTID) VALUES ('1','6586');
INSERT INTO targettable (CANID,ACCTID) VALUES ('2','6658');
INSERT INTO targettable (CANID,ACCTID) VALUES ('2','6969');
INSERT INTO targettable (CANID,ACCTID) VALUES ('3','2245');
INSERT INTO targettable (CANID,ACCTID) VALUES ('4','2365');
```

I have tried recursive CTE but it's not working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to join the two tables and use window functions to generate the *missing* rows in the source table, by comparing the count of rows per `canid` in the source to a `row_number()` over`canid` partitions in the target.

Then, all that is left to do is insert to the target table, using `row_number()` to increment the maximum `canid` as needed:

```
insert into sourcetable (canid, colid, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
select 
    max_can_id + row_number() over(order by s.canid),
    s.colid,
    s.value1,
    s.value2,
    s.value3,
    s.value4,
    s.value5
from (
    select 
        s.*, 
        count(*) over(partition by canid) cnt,
        max(canid) over() max_can_id
    from sourcetable s
) s
inner join (
    select canid, row_number() over(partition by canid order by (select null)) rn
    from targettable
) t on t.canid = s.canid and s.cnt < t.rn
```

This query will happily generate several rows if needed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=752f24ec894ca284a9430969f24011ac)**:

```
CANID | COLID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3  | Value4 | Value5
----: | ----: | :----- | :----- | :------ | :----- | :-----
    1 |    21 | 0.25   | 6.25   | Chicago | -0.25  | 16    
    2 |    65 | 0.65   | 6.19   | Dallas  | 0.15   | 65    
    3 |    91 | 1.65   | 3.25   | Denver  | NULL   | 65    
    4 |    55 | 1      | 42     | Miami   | 0.25   | NULL  
    5 |    65 | 0.65   | 6.19   | Dallas  | 0.15   | 65
```